# Clash of clans game data tranfer from one device to another android device

Tags: data-transfer, clash-of-clans

Is it possible for me to transfer game data files from my nokia-x phone to another android device?cause **Nokia-x doesn't support google play services**,and i want save my village progress.how can i get the game data files?

Comment: Can you log in with Facebook?  You can also use Facebook for game transfer.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use file explorer to find the data inside phone storage or your micro sd card (depending on where you have the app stored) under Android and data or obb.  If the game data is compatible with the version installed on your new phone, then it should be able to be copied and pasted in place of the game data from the new app.  I do not play this game but have successfully done this with other apps.  It is similar to a backup, but more specific.

Comment: An example would definitely help.

Answer (score 1):

You don’t need  to get game data files to transfer to a new device. Clash of clans data is stored on their server.

Instead, go into clash of clans and create a supercell ID. Then login to your supercell ID on your new device.

I play clash of clans and have done this with my devices before. Let me know if you have any problems